# How to use a <form> tag within a coldfusion <cfscript>

Tags: coldfusion, cfml

Trying to convert a `<cfif>` statement into it's `if` script counterpart but it's body contains a `<form>` tag.

This is located within an `onRequestStart` method within my `application.cfc` file.

CF

```
<cfscript>
    if (!isdefined("session.username")) {
        include "TEMP_Head.cfm";
        </cfscript>
        <form action="index.cfm" method="Post">
                        <input type="submit" name="LogOutUser" value="Log Out">
                </form>
        <cfscript>
        include "TEMP_Foot.cfm";
    }
</cfscript>
```

I expected this to run but I get the error message:

The start tag must have a matching end tag. An explicit end tag can be provided by adding `</cfscript>`. If the body of the tag is empty, you can use the shortcut `<cfscript .../>`.

Comment: You can't split an `if` command that way. Also, the `<form>` tag is basically output, so it must be wrapped in `WriteOutput()` [like this](https://trycf.com/gist/296f352cf174082ca1351b3e3ee25138/acf2018?theme=monokai).

Answer (score 4):

If you're dead set on this, as @Ageax commented, the form is just a string of HTML. You can try this:

```
<cfscript>
    if (structKeyExists(session, "username")) {
        var loginForm = '<form action="index.cfm" method="Post">';
        loginForm &= '<input type="submit" name="LogOutUser" value="Log Out">';
        loginForm &= '</form>';

        include "TEMP_Head.cfm";
        writeOutput(loginForm);
        include "TEMP_Foot.cfm";
    }
</cfscript>
```

Personally, I'd put the form in its own include in order to avoid putting presentation code in `Application.cfc`.

Also, per James' answer, live in the now! Stop using `isDefined()` and use `structKeyExists()` or `structname.keyExists()` depending on which version of CF you're using.

Comment: *avoid putting presentation code in Application.cfc* Ohh.. I missed that. +1, it's not the best place for it

Comment: Like @Ageax said, I would do a redirect or cflocation to a login page.

Answer (score 3):

I wouldn't even do `cfscript` on this on

```
<cfif NOT isdefined("session.username")>
    <cfinclude template="TEMP_Head.cfm">
    <form action="index.cfm" method="Post">
        <input type="submit" name="LogOutUser" value="Log Out">
    </form>
    <cfinclude template="TEMP_Foot.cfm">
</cfif>
```

**OffTopic**

`IsDefined()` isn't the cleanest way to check for variables. Consider

```
<cfif NOT session.keyExists("username")>
```

Comment: I didn't know that .keyExists() was a thing.  I've been using structKeyExists() forever.  Do you know what versions of CF support that member function?

Comment: I think CF 11 was the first version to have it.

Answer (score 2):

You can use code like below ( Include another cfm page, within that page write your HTML form code ) It will not give any error.

```
    <cfscript>
      if (!isdefined("session.username")) {
        include "TEMP_Head.cfm";  //Your Header part
        include "form_include.cfm"; // Your Form
        include "TEMP_Foot.cfm";   //Your Footer part 
      }
   </cfscript>
```

Within `form_include.cfm` use your HTML form code.

```
    <form action="index.cfm" method="Post">
      <input type="submit" name="LogOutUser" value="Log Out">
    </form>
```

[image: REsult as screenshot]